# Windows is complaining that my product key is being used on another computer. The license says I can do that. What gives?

Tags: windows-8, windows-activation

I got Windows 8 from the Dreamspark Premium program with my university. [The EULA](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rscHnaIivfZiMKbFhJbLJOjiv25NeZQqxgYnJaH1YsM/edit) states:

> 3.b. Installation and Use Rights. You may install and use on your devices  **no more than two copies of each of the software** offerings made available to you through the Student Subscription, but only (a) to support your education; (b) in non-commercial research; or (c) to design, develop, test, and demonstrate software programs for the above purposes. The Student Subscription and software are personal to you. You may not permit others to access the software using your Student Subscription. You may not transfer your Student Subscription.

Now, one of my two computers claims to have deactivated because the product code is also being used elsewhere. The only option Microsoft prominently gives me is "Buy a product code." No, thank you.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While grabbing information to [call support](https://superuser.com/a/542086/442), I noticed that the product key mismatched. My Windows 8 license key ended in 9KT67, while the computer reported a license key ending in C9T8D. Actually, this is true on *both* computers! What gives?

What gives is that I took advantage of Microsoft's limited time offer to [add Windows Media Center for free](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/feature-packs) and got a product key for my trouble. I then used it on one of my two computers.

Microsoft sent an email reminding me that the code must be used before January 31st, so I took *the same code* and also used it on my other computer. Thing is, *that* product key only works on one computer; Windows thus got deactivated.

I provided a different email address and am now waiting for a new product code; Windows doesn't accept the original product code anymore because it is for a different version of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is contact Microsoft.  Dreamspark has a support [page](https://www.dreamspark.com/Institution/Support.aspx) with a phone number.

I can honestly say from personal experience, if you contact MS, they will resolve any issue you have.

Comment: Thanks for forcing me to see the _real_ issue before attempting to make a free toll call on a Saturday :)